# Using external SSL Trust/Key stores in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, google-secret-manager

I have a Spring Boot app which I have deployed on a docker container on Google Compute Engine which uses a TrustStore and KeyStore for TLS. Currently, these p12 files are directly on the /src/main/resources/ path within the jar files. I'd like to externalize them and pull them from Google SecretManager on application load. The application utilizes Undertow.

I have the following settings:

```
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    trust-store-password: change-me
    #trust-store: # to be set programmatically during launch
    client-auth: need
    #key-store: # to be set programmatically during launch
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: my-alias
    key-store-password: change-me
    key-password: change-me
    trust-store-type: PKCS12
```

And I'm attempting to do something along the lines of this in order to set the trust-store property.

```
@Configuration
class SSLStoreConfig {

    private final String trustStore = "my-trust-store.p12"

    @Autowired
    SecretManagerTemplate secretManagerTemplate

    @PostConstruct
    private void configureSSL() {

       byte[] secretBytes = secretManagerTemplate.getSecretBytes("sm://trust-store")

        Path filePath = Paths.get(trustStore)

        try {
            Files.write(filePath, secretBytes)
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to write bytes" + e.toString())
        }
        String value = filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString()
        System.setProperty("server.ssl.trust-store", value)

    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void removeStores() {
        Path filePath = Paths.get(trustStore)
        Files.delete(filePath)
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is just for the trust-store. Once I'm able to set this successfully I can add the KeyStore as well.

How can I pull these files from GCP SecretManager and successfully reference them for the server.ssl configuration properties?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot GCP? https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/reference/html/#secret-manager

Comment: Yes, that's how I'm able to autowire and use SecretManagerTemplate